# wordpress if else syntax for multiple slugs?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, slug

I'm currently adding this to the header.php page to add a script to a single wordpress page:

```
<?php if( $post->post_name == "my-page" ) { ?>
//script here
<?php } ?>
```

Works great. how do I add another page to this? I tried:

```
<?php if( $post->post_name == array("my-page", "my-page-two") ) { ?>
//script here
<?php } ?>
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You want to check if `$post->post_name` is ***in*** your ***array*** : `array("my-page", "my-page-two")` *hint, hint*

Comment: sorry, i should mention i'm not a php coder. i tried `<?php if( $post->post_name == (in_array("my-page", "my-page-two")) ) { ?>` but didn't work

Comment: You already found the correct function. Now you just need to put it together correctly: `if(in_array($post->post_name, array("my-page", "my-page-two")))` Now `in_array()` will return TRUE if your value is in the array, and otherwise FALSE.

Comment: if you don't know how to use a function always look into the manual at the examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: @Rizier123 worked, thanks mate. I don't see the "accepted answer" checkmark?